# WooCommerce Subscriptions: Is there a hook for a manual payment retry?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I have Woocommerce orders that are pending payment. At the moment when an order hits the automatic retry payment schedule it pulls the payment information from the subscription, which works great as the customer may have corrected their wrong details by then.

But in some cases, we need to manually retry the payment. When this is done, it doesn't pull the payment information from the subscription (as the customer may have corrected their details for it to go through).

Is there a hook/action that I can use to fire the following code? `woocommerce_subscriptions_before_payment_retry` doesn't seem to work.

```
add_action('woocommerce_subscriptions_before_payment_retry', 'remove_payment_details', 10, 2 );
function remove_payment_details( $order_id ){

  $order         = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // Order Object
  $subscriptions = wcs_get_subscriptions_for_order( $order_id, array( 'order_type' => 'any' ) ); // Array of subscriptions Objects

  foreach( $subscriptions as $subscription_id => $subscription ){
       $stripe_cust_id = $subscription->get_meta( '_stripe_customer_id');
       $stripe_src_id  = $subscription->get_meta( '_stripe_source_id' );

       $order->update_meta_data( '_stripe_customer_id', $stripe_cust_id );
       $order->update_meta_data( '_stripe_source_id', $stripe_src_id );
       $order->save();
  }

}
```

[image]

Comment: I think that you should ask WooCommerce support or in 2 days add a big Bounty on this thread, Making some testable code example that can be reproduced.

Comment: Have you tried firing the action through your code? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54575/fire-a-hook-programmatically. `add_action` is supposed to be used by plugin developers to create a new hook for you. So i believe you should fire the action using `do_action(woocommerce_subscriptions_before_payment_retry, order_id)`

Answer (score 0):

Please check `woocommerce_order_action_wcs_retry_renewal_payment` hook.
The hook is for "Retry Renewal Payment" handling, and you can use it.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_action_wcs_retry_renewal_payment', 'custom_process_retry_renewal_payment_action_request', 20, 1 );

function custom_process_retry_renewal_payment_action_request( $order ) {
    // your code is here
}
```

Comment: does that fire if I manually trigger the order via the admin on the order itself?

Comment: @Rob Yes, the hook is called when you click the "Retry Renewal Payment".

Comment: @Rob, If my answer was helpful, please accept it so that I can earn the gracious bounty :-)